# Do vulnerability scanners scan source code or an executable (binary)?

Tags: security

I would like to know whether vulnerability scanners can scan binary files for vulnerabilities or can they scan source code only ?

Comment: It depends on the scanner. Which scanner did you mean? Different ones scan different things. If the question is "are there source scanners and are there also binary scanners," the answer is yes. There are also ones that scan neither (they send data and scan responses).

Comment: @Rob Napier thanks. I didn't have any one in mind just in general. You have answered my question. If you post an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the scanner. Which scanner did you mean? Different ones scan different things. If the question is "are there source scanners and are there also binary scanners," the answer is yes. There are also ones that scan neither (they send data and scan responses).